# Handle NSNumber and NSInteger

Tags: ios, nsmutablearray, nsinteger

Following is a code snippet i am using to add data to nsmutable array, now I am not sure on what to type cast it on while extracting, i need integer value.
Problem is that I am getting warnings of 'id' and 'NSInteger' conversion. What could be better way of extracting:

```
    self.itemsBottom = [NSMutableArray array];
    for (int i = 20; i < 30; i++)
    {
        [itemsBottom addObject:@(i)];
    }
```

wanna do something like:

```
NSInteger itemAddressed = [self.itemsBottom objectAtIndex:itemIndex]
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to convert NSNumber to NSInteger](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2355088/how-to-convert-nsnumber-to-nsinteger)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In this statement

```
[itemsBottom addObject:@(i)];
```

you are boxing the `integer` value to `NSNumber`.

While here

```
NSInteger itemAddressed = [self.itemsBottom objectAtIndex:itemIndex]
```

you are tried to store NSNumber to NSInteger, hence getting the error.

You can use :

```
NSInteger itemAddressed = [[self.itemsBottom objectAtIndex:itemIndex] integerValue];
```

Or in short :

```
NSInteger itemAddressed = [self.itemsBottom[itemIndex] integerValue];
```

Answer (score 2):

All seems reasonable...I would think the last line would need to be...

```
NSInteger itemAddressed = [self.itemsBottom[itemIndex] integerValue];
```

Maybe?